# How do I add an HTTP Authorization header to a REST call in PeopleSoft?

Tags: http-headers, peoplesoft

I need to consume a REST endpoint that is protected by OAuth. To do this I need to be able to add an Authorization : Bearer xxxxx header to my call. Is it possible to do this without using the PeopleSoft Integration Hub?

edit: changed Integration Broker to Integration Hub.

Comment: How are you calling the REST service if you are not using the Integration Broker?

Comment: Sorry, I confused the products. The product we don't have is Integration Hub. I will update the question. (I don't work with PeopleSoft directly... My code is the OAuth producer and am trying to help another department call my OAuth endpoint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom headers via PeopleCode.

```
&MSG = CreateMessage(OPERATION.SOME_REST_OPERATION)
&result = &MSG.IBInfo.IBConnectorInfo.AddConnectorProperties("Authorization", "Bearer xxxxx", %Header); 
/* TODO: Populate message with values */
%IntBroker.SyncRequest(&MSG);
```

[Related PeopleBooks Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E58500_01/pt854pbh1/eng/pt/tpcr/langref_IBConnectorInfoCollectionMethods-0711fb.html#topofpage)

Comment: Thanks. I marked this as the answer even though I haven't tried it. I am told that in the past year we have received updates and that they can now do that. There are other challenges but that one at least I believe has been overcome.

Answer (score 2):

Darryls99 is correct.

In addition:

For HTTPS communications, you also need to have the TLS certificate chain imported on your IB gateway web servers. Put the certs in the PIA key store, and bounce the web server.

I have done a lot of OAuth 'stuff' with PeopleSoft. It works well!